# Powershell/C#: Invoking a pipeline asynchronously & displaying the results

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

As per this sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706590(v=vs.85).aspx,

I am trying to invoke my script in an async way. But, at the same time, I want to give feedback to the GUI on the set of operations happening i.e. want to spit the Write-verbose stuffs happening behind the scenes parallely on the GUI.

I am confused in achieving this - because I see there is a [DataReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms567691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on the PipelineReader object ? Is it possible to somehow consume that w.r.t the **MSDN sample above** such that I can show feedback on the GUI ?

> Conceptually, I am not able to relate ***[this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** with the [***DataReady***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms567691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Got it ! Here is the full code...*

**Add a Rich Textbox = txtOutput on a Form first** 
& **Add a reference to**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll

```
    IAsyncResult _invokeResult; 

    PowerShell _ps = PowerShell.Create();

    delegate void SetOutput(string value);

    // Monitor the DataAdded
    _ps.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += new EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs>(Verbose_DataAdded);

    var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyScript.ps1");
    _ps.AddScript(sr.ReadToEnd());
    _invokeResult = _ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject>(null, null, AsyncInvoke, null);


   void Verbose_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>) sender)[e.Index].ToString()) ;

       if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
       {
           string msg = ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>) sender)[e.Index].ToString();
           txtOutput.Invoke(new SetOutput(Execute), new object[] { msg} );
       }
   }



   void AsyncInvoke(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       // end
       try
       {
           _ps.EndInvoke(ar);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
             // do something with the error...
       }
  }

private void Execute(string msg)
        {
            txtOutput.SelectionFont = new Font(txtOutput.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 9.0f);
            txtOutput.AppendText(msg);
            txtOutput.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

Comment: It would be interesting know how to invoking a pipeline asynchronously in remote compute and displaying the results, using PowerShell and C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9831617/763026 - Might be this is what you wanted ? But, anyways I will give it a shot soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to output Write-Verbose output to the GUI then it would be easier to monitor the [Streams.Verbose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) collection after the InvokeAsync.  If you want to scan all the output then use the PipelineReader.  Subscribe to its DataReady event and in that event handler do a NonBlockingRead to get the data.

Comment: I tried using Streams.Verbose.DataAdded event. This works fine - System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>) sender)[e.Index].ToString()), but when I try to show it on a GUI in a thread safe way, it just stops working. Any sample on how to monitor and display the results on  "GUI" form just like the way we deal with progress bars ?