# GUI Overlay over Powershell Script

Tags: user-interface, powershell, installation

I need to create a GUI overlay that will provide status information to users while an install is taking place.  The install happens through Powershell scripts.  I would rather not rewrite the functionality that is already taking place in the scripts.

Are there any practical methods I can use to overlay a GUI over the scripts?  I am thinking of something along the lines of an application installer that just calls the scripts and displays information about the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run [PowerShell scripts from CSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) and interact with the PS runspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can always wrap up these scripts in WinForms (PrimalForms Community Edition to design the UI) within PowerShell or use something like ShowUI (showui.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 1):

Anything particularly wrong with using Write-Progress calls in your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an install cum config tool and this is what I did to run the PS scripts asynchronously from C#/Winforms - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741061/763026 [Full code is there]