# c# executing powershell and reading stdout asynchronously

Tags: c#

I have the same question as [Powershell/C#: Invoking a pipeline asynchronously & displaying the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723264/powershell-c-invoking-a-pipeline-asynchronously-displaying-the-results)

I wish to get the stdout and stderror of System.Management.Automation.Powershell in c#
and display it on GUI while it is executing since the process is very long and I need to actively display what's happening.
It is not firing up the handlers that I've added.
I've put break points...
Any ideas why it's not firing off?

```
delegate void SetOutput(string value);
PowerShell ps;

private void LocalExec()
{
    string script = "ls C:\";
    Collection<PSObject> results = null;
    ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddScript(script);
    ps.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += new EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs>(Verbose_DataAdded);
    IAsyncResult res = ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject>(null, null, AsyncInvoke, null);
}

void AsyncInvoke(IAsyncResult res)
{
    try
    {
        ps.EndInvoke(res);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void PsDataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}

void Verbose_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString());

    if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
    {
        string msg = ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString();
        txtOutput.Invoke(new SetOutput(Execute), new object[] { msg });
    }
}

private void Execute(string msg)
{
    txtOutput.AppendText(msg);
    txtOutput.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with the `PowerShell` class specifically, but two things pop out here: first, you are handling just the `Verbose` stream (so if the script executed doesn't output to that stream, you won't see anything), and second you are disposing the `PowerShell` object before it has completed its work (which may or may not interfere with the handling of the event, but in any case seems non-kosher). But for a good answer, you need to post [a good code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I removed the using block. The problem exists. The code above is from my synchronous code that was already working and I modified it to be very similar to the other stackoverflow posting.

Comment: I've found a good sample that works fine with RunSpace rather than Powershell class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18409/Asynchronously-Execute-PowerShell-Scripts-from-C   It solves the problem for me. Nevertheless, I welcome comments on whether the powershell class can be used or whether there is a simpler way.